# Middle lines in octagon are congruent

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

> Let $A_1A_2\dots A_8$ be a cyclic octagon. Suppose that $A_1A_6||A_2A_5, A_3A_8||A_4A_7$, and that $A_2A_5\perp A_3A_8$. Prove that the length of the two midline segmets, one connecting the midpoints of sides $A_8A_1, A_4A_5$, and the other connecting sides $A_2A_3, A_6A_7$ are equal.

[image]

Here is an (ugly) solution with (position) vectors: Let $M_{ij}$ be the
midpoint of a chord $A_iA_j$. Let $\vec{a}$ be a vector between midpoints of segments $A_2A_5$ and $A_1A_6$ so $$\vec{a}=\overrightarrow{M_{52}M_{16}} =M_{16}-M_{52} $$ 
and $\vec{b}$ be a vector between midpoints of segments $A_4A_7$ and $A_3A_8$ so $$\vec{b}=\overrightarrow{M_{47}M_{38}} =M_{38}-M_{47} $$ 
Notice that $\vec{a}\bot \vec{b}$ and  $\overrightarrow{A_7A_4} || \overrightarrow{A_8A_3}||\vec{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{A_2A_5} ||\overrightarrow{A_1A_6}||\vec{b}$.
Then \begin{eqnarray}
4\overline{M_{18}M_{45}}^2 -4\overline{{M_{23}M_{67}}}^2 &=&  4\overrightarrow{M_{18}M_{45}}^2 -4\overrightarrow{M_{23}M_{67}}^2 \\
 &=&  (2\overrightarrow{M_{18}M_{45}} -2\overrightarrow{M_{23}M_{67}})(2\overrightarrow{M_{18}M_{45}}+2\overrightarrow{M_{23}M_{67}}) \\
  &=&  (A_4+A_5 -A_1-A_8-A_6-A_7 +A_3+A_2)\cdot \\&&(A_4+A_5 -A_1-A_8+A_6+A_7 -A_3-A_2) \\
  &=&(\overrightarrow{A_7A_4} +\overrightarrow{A_8A_3}+2M_{52}-2M_{16})  \cdot \\&& (\overrightarrow{A_2A_5} +\overrightarrow{A_1A_6}+2M_{47}-2M_{38})\\
  &=&  (m\cdot\vec{b} +k\cdot \vec{b}-2\vec{b})\cdot (l\cdot \vec{a} +n\cdot \vec{a}-2\vec{a}) \\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray} and we are done.

*Can somebody find nicer solution, possibly with geometric transformations?*

Comment: Is the blue dot O the center?

Comment: Yes, and is unimportatnt in a solution i gave.

Comment: Although this is clearly not a duplicate (since it includes its own solution), a link to the original question seems desirable: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3052478/octagon-problem-cyclic-octagon-s-two-midline-segments-are-equa

Answer (score 2):

[image]If this were graphed onto a coordinate plane temporarily, focus on the y-values of all points $A_1,A_2,...,A_8$.

We know that $A_1=A_6$ and $A_2=A_5$, while $A_3+A_8=A_4+A_7$ since they are parallel chords. So, $\frac{A_1+A_2+A_3+A_8}{4}=\frac{A_4+A_5+A_6+A_7}{4}$. This is important because if we rewrite it, it is $\frac{\frac{A_1+A_8}{2} +\frac{A_2+A_3}{2}}{2}$=$\frac{\frac{A_7+A_6}{2} +\frac{A_4+A_5}{2}}{2}$, translating into $\frac{M_{18}+M_{23}}{2}=\frac{M_{67}+M_{45}}{2}$.

So when we draw lines $M_{18}M_{23}$ and $M_{67}M_{45}$, their midpoints $M_{1823}$ and $M_{6745}$ have the same y-values. The two lines are also parallel, so the perpendicular bisectors of both $M_{18}M_{23}$ and $M_{67}M_{45}$ is the same line. For convenience, assume that this perpendicular bisector crosses over the black point in the diagram, call it K. By the properties of a perpendicular bisector on both $M_{18}M_{23}$ and $M_{67}M_{45}$, $KM_{67}=KM_{45}$ and $KM_{18}=KM_{23}$.

Also, angle $M_{18}KM_{67}$ is congruent to the angle $M_{23}KM_{45}$, meaning that $M_{18}KM_{67}+M_{67}KM_{45}$=$M_{23}KM_{45}+M_{67}KM_{45}$ so $M_{18}KM_{45}=M_{67}KM_{23}$.

Thus, by SAS, triangles $M_{18}KM_{45}$ and $M_{67}KM_{23}$ are congruent, meaning that $M_{67}M_{23}=M_{18}M_{45}$ and we're done.

Comment: Why is this true:  angle $M_{18}KM_{67}$ is congruent to the angle $M_{23}KM_{45}$?

Comment: Sorry for the relatively messy diagram, but I added a picture showing why

Comment: How do you know that that green line actualy separate 2A and 2B angles?

Comment: +1 for effort :)

Comment: Haha, yea sorry for not being so clear about it. Since we proved that the green line is a perpendicular bisector for both $M_{18}M_{23}$ and $M_{45}M_{67}$, we can draw the two pairs of congruent right triangles on the right and on the left. By SAS, the two right side triangles and two left side triangles are congruent, meaning that the corresponding angles of the triangles are congruent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution motivated by **Muchang Bahng** writings:

Set a coordinate system so that perpendicular bisector for $A_4A_7$ (which is also for $A_3A_8$) be a x-axsis and a perpenduclar bisector for $A_1A_6$ (which is also for $A_2A_4$) be a y-axsis, in particular, let $$ M_{17}= (2b,0)\;\;\;\; {\rm and } \;\;\;\;M_{38}= (-2a,0)$$ and
$$ M_{25}= (0,-2d)\;\;\;\; {\rm and } \;\;\;\;M_{16}= (0,2c)$$

then $$ A_{1}= (-2k,2c)\;\;\;\; {\rm and } \;\;\;\;A_{6}= (2k,2c)$$ 
$$ A_{2}= (-2l,-2d)\;\;\;\; {\rm and } \;\;\;\;A_{5}= (2l,-2d)$$
 $$ A_{3}= (-2a,-2m)\;\;\;\; {\rm and } \;\;\;\;A_{8}= (-2a,2m)$$
 $$ A_{4}= (2b,-2n)\;\;\;\; {\rm and } \;\;\;\;A_{7}= (2b,2n)$$ 
thus $$ M_{18}= (-a-k,c+d)\;\;\;\; {\rm and } \;\;\;\;M_{23}= (-l-a,-m-a)$$ 
$$ M_{45}= (l+b,-n-d)\;\;\;\; {\rm and } \;\;\;\;M_{67}= (b+k,n+c)$$ 
So $$ \overline{M_{18}M_{45}}^2 = (c+m+n+d)^2+(l+b+a+k)^2 = \overline{M_{23}M_{67}}^2$$
and we are done.

Hmm, much easier then first solution and we never used that $A_i$ are actualy on a circle!